# Remove Parent element child elements href has no property

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I was trying to remove the parent element if the child element href has no attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var noImg = "";
  var cPathName = window.location.pathname;

  if (noImg) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  }
});

$(".dnext-thumbs-gallery-top-image-link").filter(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('href').length == 0) {
    console.log('test');
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cs-gallery" class="et_pb_with_border et_pb_module dnxte_thumbs_gallery_parent dnxte_thumbs_gallery_parent_0_tb_body">
  <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
    <div class="dnext_thumbs_gallery_top_holder">
      <div class="swiper-container dnext-thumbs-gallery-top swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper dnext-thumbs-gallery-active" data-lightbox="on">
          <div class="et_pb_module dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child_0_tb_body swiper-slide">

            <div class="et_pb_module_inner dnext-thumbs-gallery-item">
              <a href="" class="dnext-thumbs-gallery-top-image-link" data-title="Logo Item"><img class="img-fluid" alt="Logo Item" src=""></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="et_pb_module dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child_1_tb_body swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev" style="width: 1080px; margin-right: 10px;">

            <div class="et_pb_module_inner dnext-thumbs-gallery-item">
              <a href="https://adroithd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/WhatsApp-Image-2022-03-28-at-11.45.05-AM.jpeg" class="dnext-thumbs-gallery-top-image-link" data-title="Logo Item"><img class="img-fluid" alt="Logo Item" src="https://adroithd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/WhatsApp-Image-2022-03-28-at-11.45.05-AM.jpeg.webp"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I trying to filter. got an error

```
$(...).filter is not a function
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: your code seams to work fine ? you could try replacing filter with each method see if that works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use each instead of filter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var noImg = "";
  var cPathName = window.location.pathname;

  if (noImg) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  }
});

$(".dnext-thumbs-gallery-top-image-link").each(function(i, e) {
  if ($(e).attr('href').length == 0) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cs-gallery" class="et_pb_with_border et_pb_module dnxte_thumbs_gallery_parent dnxte_thumbs_gallery_parent_0_tb_body">
  <div class="et_pb_module_inner">
    <div class="dnext_thumbs_gallery_top_holder">
      <div class="swiper-container dnext-thumbs-gallery-top swiper-container-initialized swiper-container-horizontal">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper dnext-thumbs-gallery-active" data-lightbox="on">
          <div class="et_pb_module dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child_0_tb_body swiper-slide">

            <div class="et_pb_module_inner dnext-thumbs-gallery-item">
              <a href="" class="dnext-thumbs-gallery-top-image-link" data-title="Logo Item"><img class="img-fluid" alt="Logo Item" src=""></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="et_pb_module dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child dnxte_thumbs_gallery_child_1_tb_body swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev" style="width: 1080px; margin-right: 10px;">

            <div class="et_pb_module_inner dnext-thumbs-gallery-item">
              <a href="https://adroithd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/WhatsApp-Image-2022-03-28-at-11.45.05-AM.jpeg" class="dnext-thumbs-gallery-top-image-link" data-title="Logo Item"><img class="img-fluid" alt="Logo Item" src="https://adroithd.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/WhatsApp-Image-2022-03-28-at-11.45.05-AM.jpeg.webp"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```